# .htaccess for Different Folder Paths on Server vs. Dev Environment?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter-routing

I'm moving my app (a CodeIgniter app-- I'm not sure if that is relevant) to a new web host and have to resolve some questions about pathing.

On my localhost dev environment, everything is working. Here is the folder layout:

> - Root Directory
>
>   - Application

Here is the folder layout on my web host:

> - Root Directory
>
>   - xyz folder
>
>     - Application

If I visit the following URL in my browser, I get a 404 error:

> http://myDomainName/xyz

Is there a way to correct this via .htaccess?

Thanks very much in advance to all for any info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try configuring your config.php (application/config/config.php) to point to the correct base url for your webapp.

This line should be included in the file:

$config [‘base_url'] = http://myDomainName/xyz